# how do I know what version of gjslint I have installed?

Tags: javascript, lint, gjslint

This may be a dumb question, but I cannot figure it out. Doing gjslint --help does not provide the answer, and --version is not a valid flag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command:

```
cat `which gjslint` | grep [0-9] --color=always
```

or

```
cat $(which gjslint) | grep [0-9] --color=always
```

Comment: to find the path to gjslint use "which gslint"

Comment: @powtac, thanks. I had realized there would be a better way, so I [asked on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48149/how-to-cat-filename-returned-by-which/48150#48150) and learnt something new!

Comment: I'm not sure, is `grep [0-9]` enough?

Comment: It's barely enough to *highlight* the numbers in that file. My bashrc was set up with color always on for grep. I'll update the answer in case the OP does not have that enabled!

Comment: Did you run the complete command I mention in my answer? What was your result? I ran it on my box and it highlighted the version number. I don't understand why you downvoted it.

Comment: Zabba! Sorry, you are right! I should have tried the whole command. My vote is locked, but if you just briefly edit your answer I can change my vote. I will upvote. Apologies, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner prints out only the version number, convenient eg. if you want to use it in a script:

```
which gjslint | xargs cat | grep "ENTRY-SCRIPT" | sed 's|.*closure-linter==\([.0-9]*\).*|\1|'
```